# How do I pass fetch value into a json?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I would like to pass the value variable from the one() function to the x json. The x json should not be withing the one() function or any other function. Is it possible?

```js
 function something(){
    function one() {
            
            let url = 'https://data.heroku.com/dataclips/szmszzhrbbuhxqfunbmblylxijko.json';
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((out) => out.values[out.values.length-1][2])
        .then((values2) =>  multiply(values2))
        .catch((err)=>{ throw err });
       function multiply(values) {
          var amounts = document.getElementById("amount").value;
          var amounts2 = (values * amounts);
          const value=amounts2.toString();
          console.log(value);
         return value; //#####I need to get this variable from here#####
      }
        }
      one();
     var x={purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {
             value:value,//#####to here#####
            },
          },
        ],
      };
      console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
            <p>Enter the amount:</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder=1 id="amount" name="amount">
            <button onclick="something()">submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the JSON value from the one() function like this:

```
function one() {
    let returnedValue = null

    let url = 'https://data.heroku.com/dataclips/szmszzhrbbuhxqfunbmblylxijko.json';
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => { returnedValue = res.json() })

    return returnedValue
}

const x = one()
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I get one() to return the value of multiply(values)?

Comment: Somethink like this:
```.then(res => { returnedValue = multiply(res.json()) })```

Comment: I tried  ````.then((values2) =>  returnedValue=multiply(values2))```` and its showing returnedValue as null.

Comment: Take a look: https://codepen.io/bartek-krakowski/pen/xxgrwLV?editors=0012
I update my solution with async/await

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but you helped me out, thank you.